# Subscribe to whatever method is being executed

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, .net-core

In my app I'm creating an auditing package that obtains various information, one such type of information should provide different information regarding what method is executed (time it took to execute, method name, method class, assembly, etc).

I'm not looking to use an existing package or framework, but to create my own.

I can imagine that this is a complicated thing to do, but I'm looking for some pointers to get me started .

Comment: In its most general form it's called a profiler, and while you can certainly build your own, it's far from trivial. There are less challenging options, like using code generation to instrument specific methods to call your auditing code, wrapping individual calls in a delegate, or just leaving the calling code to add its own instrumentation using the various logging/performance counter packages available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option you may be interested in is DI-level interception. Since container is responsible for your objects instantiation, sometimes it can be configured with proxy generators to enable call interception.

You can choose between [Autofac](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/interceptors.html), or [Unity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/msp-n-p/dn178467%28v%3Dpandp.30%29).

The most popular tasks to solve with this approach are cross-cutting concerns, like: logging, measurements, run-time application structure analysis. If you don't want to pollute your code base with repetitive diagnostic code, just delegate this  task to an interceptor.

Similiar idea is [AOP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming). I havn't seen popular AOP packages for a long time, and havn't used them, but it's worth to do a research on this topic too:

[What is the best implementation for AOP in .Net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/633710/what-is-the-best-implementation-for-aop-in-net)

[DI Interception vs. AOP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32251755/di-interception-vs-aop)